# Help With PHP - Get WordPress to Choose Image by Size (conditionally)?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to code this, I've researched like crazy (an hour and a half), and I finally decided to sign up for Stack Overflow to see if anyone can help, soo....

In my wordpress theme, I have a section for banners (images that are attached to posts). This is what I currently have:

```
    <?php
   $headline = new WP_Query();
   $headline->query('posts_per_page=2&tag=review&orderby=date');
?>
<div id="headline">
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "image_value", $single = true) != "") : ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "image_value", $single = true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that the width of the content area is 960px, and the banners I upload are sizes (width): 728px, 960px, and 232px. So does anyone know some PHP code that would find the width of the banners of the two posts, see if they would fit, and if they dont, just use one banner (either the 728px or the 960px), and then if the 728px is used also add the 232px image to the div so it fills in nicely?

And the selection of the images used by the code is kind of supposed to be random, I can handle that though.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You must get the width through eg. GD.  Then bother with some `if`s.

Hint: `getimagesize();`

Comment: Thanks for the get image size @Kwpolska, but how would I reference the image size if the image is being initially fetched by:

<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "image_value", $single = true) != "") : ?>

This doesn't look right...
<?php list($width) = getimagesize("<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "image_value", $single = true) != "") : ?>"); ?>

lol... But then again i did stay up all night making this theme.

Comment: @DavidG2 Get the actual image URL.  Then you can use it with `getimagesize()`.